# php-cli: What is the best way to detect the hosting OS?

Tags: php

I have a script which I want to run on windows under Cygwin and on Linux. I have to make distinction between the two running environment for some purposes. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a pre-defined constant PHP_OS which will help, but only displays the OS that PHP was built on, not the OS it is running on.

[`php_uname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php) is what you want to discover information about the current server running your code:

> **php_uname()** returns a description of the operating system PHP is running on.

Specifically,

```
php_uname('s'); // Operating system name. eg. FreeBSD.
```

Answer (score 1):

how about the PHP_OS variable?

`print PHP_OS;`

Comment: PHP_OS displays the OS that PHP was BUILT on, not the current OS.

Comment: if its built on the OS that PHP is also running on, then its fine. NOte in the docs of php_uname(), there are some caveats as well.

Comment: PHP_OS is not even a variable.